# How to apply regex in Scala on process output?

Tags: regex, scala

I'm trying to get the same output in Scala as I get from running the following command in Mac/Linux:

```
ps -ef | egrep "(mongo|mysql|rabbitmq)"
```

This is my implementation but I'm looking for an elegant one.

```
import sys.process._
import scala.collection.mutable.HashSet

object Regex {
  val set = new HashSet[String]                  
  val logger = ProcessLogger(
    (o: String) => """(mysql|mongo|rabbitmq)""".r findAllIn o foreach (set += _),
    (e: String) => println(e))                  
  "ps -ef " ! logger                             
  println(set)                 
}
```

Another approach I was trying was to invoke the "started" function from ProcessLogger but couldn't get it to work correctly.

```
val Procs = """(mysql|mongo|rabbitmq)""".r         
def started(i: String) = i match {
  case Procs(p) => p
  case _ => null
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Seq("bash", "-c", """ps -ef | egrep "(mongo|mysql|rabbitmq)"""").!
```

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can process the output line by line using `Source` and using regular collection methods:

```
io.Source
  .fromString("ps -ef".!!)
  .getLines()
  .filter(_.matches(".*(mysql|mongo).*"))
  .foreach(println)
```

Comment: How can this be done without waiting the command to complete?